# "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute" when running the same background worker on 2+ instances of a form simultaneously

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms, winforms, backgroundworker

I have a c# windows form where the user enters a set of parameters, and those parameters are then analyzed against a set of data to return a result. This analysis takes place on a background worker, by initializing a `Backtest` object and iterating over a string list `symbolParams` built from the values passed in through the form. When running the worker on one form, it works properly.

However, if I open up a second form, put in a new set of parameters, and run the worker on that form while the worker on the first form is still running, I get a "Collection was modified" error on the string list.

Seems as though the two background workers are affecting each other's `symbolParams` list somehow. What's happening? How can this be fixed to allow multiple instances of this form to run this background worker simultaneously?

OptimizerForm.cs

```
public partial class OptimizerForm : Form
{

    public static List<List<String>> backtestSymbolParams = new List<List<String>> { };

    private void button15_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        //Get parameters from the form
        //Make a list for every param
        string[] startEndTimes = textBox3.Text.Split(',');
        string[] incrementPrices = textBox4.Text.Split(',');
        string[] incrementSizes = textBox5.Text.Split(',');
        string[] autoBalances = textBox6.Text.Split(',');
        string[] hardStops = textBox7.Text.Split(',');

        //Add every combo to symbol test params
        for (int a = 0; a < startEndTimes.Length; a++)
        {
            for (int b = 0; b < incrementPrices.Length; b++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < incrementSizes.Length; c++)
                {
                    for (int d = 0; d < autoBalances.Length; d++)
                    {
                        for (int f = 0; f < hardStops.Length; f++)
                        {
                            backtestSymbolParams.Add( new List<string> { symbol, startEndTimes[a].Split('-')[0], startEndTimes[a].Split('-')[1], incrementPrices[b],
                                incrementSizes[c], autoBalances[d], hardStops[f] });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        //Initialize Backtest instance with parameters gathered from the form 
        Backtest backtest = new Backtest(backtestSymbolParams, backtestSymbolDates, sender as BackgroundWorker);

        TestResult testResult = new TestResult();

        //Run the analysis
        testResult = backtest.Run();

        e.Result = testResult;
    }
}
```

Backtest.cs

```
//Backtest Constructor
public Backtest(List<List<string>> _symbolParams, Dictionary<string,       List<string>> _symbolDates, BackgroundWorker _bw)
{
    symbolParams = _symbolParams;
    symbolDates = _symbolDates;
    bw = _bw;
}

//Backtest.Run()
public TestResult Run()
{
    int symbolCount = 1;

    //Collection modified exception occurs here
    foreach (List<string> symbolParam in symbolParams) {
       //do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't show the most important code - how do you get this `symbolParams` variable.

Comment: Added it. backtestSymbolParams is built from form values, then passed in to the Backtest constructor and assigned to symbolParams

Comment: Still don't see where `backtestSymbolParams` is defined - form variable, static variable? Why don't you use local variable and pass it to the BGW through second `RunWorkerAsync` overoload with `object argument`?

Comment: It's being defined from static variable. Just tried it removing static and now the background workers run simultaneously with no problems.  :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your `symbolParams` variable in `Backtest` class is `static`, so simply mark it as private field for your class.

Also you have some issues with naming standards - method parameters should not start with `_`, though fields should, so your constructor should looks like:

```
private List<List<String>> _symbolParams = new List<List<String>> { };

//Backtest Constructor
public Backtest(List<List<string>> symbolParams,
                Dictionary<string, List<string>> symbolDates,
                BackgroundWorker bw)
{
    _symbolParams = symbolParams;
    _symbolDates = symbolDates;
    _bw = bw;
}
```

And, as far as I can see, you're using `BackgroundWorker` as `Task` so probably you should use `TPL` itself, without old legacy classes